# Failed to call parent function from remote iframe

Tags: javascript

parent.html

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
    <head>  
    <script   type="text/javascript">  
    function say() { 
            alert("parent.html------>I'm at parent.html"); 
    } 

    function callChild() 
    {  
           myFrame.window.say(); 
    }  
    </script>  
    </head>  

    <body>    
    <input   type=button   value=" call child.html say()" onclick="callChild()"> 
    <iframe name="myFrame" src="http://66.175.214.250/child.html"></iframe> 
    </body>  
   </html>
```

child.html

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>  
   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   function say()  
   {  
        alert("child.html--->I'm at child.html");  
   } 

   function callParent() { 
        window.top.say(); 
   } 
   </script>  
   </head>  
   <body>  
   <input   type=button   value="call parent.html say() "   onclick="callParent()">  
   </body>  
   </html>
```

This is tested in localhost when parent.html and child.html in the same folder. But if I upload child.html to a remote host. There is error: The parent can not call child's function, and the child can not call parent's function.

I do not know why. It is iframe call it's parent should be local, or something in the remote host block?

Thanks

Comment: The URLs for both pages have to have the same scheme ("http" or "https"), the exact same domain name, and the same port number (if specified).

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy).

Answer (score 1):

Even something as simple as leaving the subdomain (www.) from the child frame could cause your browser to halt any and all of this communication between the two browsers as they would not be considered of the same origin or domain.